# Question about the proof of Lefschetz hyperplane Theorem

Tags: complex-geometry

I am reading page $159$ of Principles of Algebraic Geometry and a bit confused about Lefschetz hyperplane Theorem. They write:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional compact, complex manifold and $V \in M$ a smooth hypersurface with $L=[V]$ positive——e.g.,$M \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ a submanifold of projective space and $V=M \bigcap H$ a hyperplane section of $M$. then for $p \in V$, the sequence $$0\rightarrow N_{ V,p }^{ \ast  }\rightarrow T_{ p }^{ \ast \prime  }(M)\rightarrow  T_{ p }^{ \ast \prime  }(V)\rightarrow 0,$$
>   which is dual of the normal bundle sequene, yields, by linear algebra,
>   $$0\rightarrow N_{ V,p }^{ \ast  }\otimes { \wedge  }^{ p-1 }T_{ p }^{ \ast \prime  }(V)\rightarrow { \wedge  }^{ p }T_{ p }^{ \ast \prime  }(M)\rightarrow { \wedge  }^{ p }T_{ p }^{ \ast \prime  }(V)\rightarrow 0,$$
>   and consequently an exact sequence of sheaves on $V$
>   $$0\rightarrow \Omega_V^{p-1}(-V)- \Omega_M^{p}|_V\rightarrow \Omega_V^{p}\rightarrow 0.$$

---

Now, I don't understand how do we get the second exact sequence, and  know that $\Omega_M^{p}(-V)$ is clearly just the sheaf of holomorphic $p$-forms on $M$ vanishing along $V$, so does $\Omega_V^{p-1}(-V)$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear Zhu, they explain that they are using the adjuntion formula I, so I don't see what is your doubt. By the way, my mother tongue isn't english, clearly, so I understand the reason you write "Thanks in advance", but it's actually offencive, it's better "I'd appreciate any help".

Comment: @user90189 thanks